# Entity Framework don't show properly level of relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to EntityFramework and I have a problem with the multiple levels of my Web Api response.

I want to get all Armas including collections like Elemento1, but when the collection is included the response includes data I don't expect to see.

I have lazy-loading disabled. I don't know why this occurs.

This is my service method:

```
public IEnumerable<Arma> GetAllArmas()
{
    return uow.RepositoryClient<Arma>().getDbSet().Include("Elemento1");
}
```

And this my generic getWithInclude method

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params string[] include)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
    query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc));
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

I'm getting this response

```
[{
        "Elemento1": {
            "Arma": [
                {
                    "Estadistica1": null,
                    "Inventario1": null,
                    "NombreArma": null,
                    "Rareza1": null,
                    "armaId": 4,
                    "nombre": 1,
                    "rareza": 1,
                    "daño": 10,
                    "esquiva": 2,
                    "defensa": 3,
                    "alcance": 1,
                    "estadistica": 1,
                    "bonus": 1.5,
                    "elemento": 1,
                    "descripcion": "Descripcion Daga",
                    "equipado": true,
                    "peso": null,
                    "durabilidad": null,
                    "inventario": 1
                }
            ],
            "Armadura": [],
            "Elemento1": [],
            "Elemento2": null,
            "Habilidad": [],
            "elementoId": 1,
            "nombre": "Fuego",
            "rango": 10,
            "daño": 10,
            "debufo": 1,
            "debilidad": 2,
            "descripcion": "Descripcion de Fuego"
        },
        "Estadistica1": null,
        "Inventario1": null,
        "NombreArma": null,
        "Rareza1": null,
        "armaId": 1,
        "nombre": 1,
        "rareza": 1,
        "daño": 10,
        "esquiva": 2,
        "defensa": 3,
        "alcance": 1,
        "estadistica": 1,
        "bonus": 1.5,
        "elemento": 1,
        "descripcion": "Descripcioasdasdasdn Daga",
        "equipado": true,
        "peso": null,
        "durabilidad": null,
        "inventario": 1
    }]
```

And I want something like this

```
{
        "Elemento1": {
            "elementoId": 1,
            "nombre": "Fuego",
            "rango": 10,
            "daño": 10,
            "debufo": 1,
            "debilidad": 2,
            "descripcion": "Descripcion de Fuego"
        },
        "Estadistica1": null,
        "Inventario1": null,
        "NombreArma": null,
        "Rareza1": null,
        "armaId": 1,
        "nombre": 1,
        "rareza": 1,
        "daño": 10,
        "esquiva": 2,
        "defensa": 3,
        "alcance": 1,
        "estadistica": 1,
        "bonus": 1.5,
        "elemento": 1,
        "descripcion": "Descripcion Daga",
        "equipado": true,
        "peso": null,
        "durabilidad": null,
        "inventario": 1
    }
```

Comment: Is Arma an OwnedObject in your EF Mapping? This question should only apply if you are mapping to a non-relational store like Azure Cosmos.

Comment: @TeaBaerd Arma inside Elemento1 is a collection of all Armas that have in this case Elemento1 "Fuego", and i'm using sql server as db. I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: that does answer my question and disproves my theory.